# Jmeter load testing not working for multiple users

Tags: multithreading, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have configured my setup as shown in the image ->

[image: Jmeter screenshot]

I intend to run a setup thread once at the beginning and a teardown thread once at the end. In between these two threads, I aim to perform load testing on API setups within the middle thread, involving 500 users.

However, there is an issue with the current setup. While the setup and teardown threads operate as expected, the middle thread executes for only one user, even though I have specified two users in the CSV. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights to address this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 19 errors since you started your JMeter or cleared the previous results, maybe not all of them are for your current test run, but it still worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it might be the case you will find the reason of the 2nd thread not starting there:

[image]

I would also expect the threads counter to show `0/3` rather than `0/1` so most probably your "Test sumbmission" thread group is not being executed at all because the file referenced in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) either cannot be found or empty or something is wrong with the setup of the CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: The second thread is currently executing only for the first user in the CSV file and is not functioning for the remaining users in the CSV. I'm seeking assistance to understand and resolve this issue. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: With the default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All Threads` each thread reads the next line from the CSV file on each iteration. If you changed the default sharing mode then you need to ask yourself why, not us.

Comment: Sharing Mode is set to All Threads. It is not changed.

Comment: You're either misconfigured something and not willing to show what or lying or both. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGgK6.gif) is example setup showing that with Sharing Mode `All Threads` each thread picks next line, just replicate it and use. Otherwise you might want to check what [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are defined using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

Comment: The problem originated from the JMeter GUI, where despite configuring the number of users as 2, the logs were displaying threads as 1. However, the issue was resolved when executing the test through the command line. Thanks for your time @Dmitri T .

Answer (score 0):

The problem originated from the JMeter GUI, where despite configuring the number of users as 2, the logs were displaying threads as 1. However, the issue was resolved when executing the test through the command line.

Attempt executing your JMX file via the command line; this might address the problem, as I identified certain issues when running it through the GUI.

> jmeter -n -t "JMX_FILE_PATH" -l "results.csv"